# Bigcommerce Product update API

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am using bigcommerce API to update product inventory values . There are about 3000 products to be updated.. With API a few hundred gets updated but after that it gives "could not connect to host". I am using same code on github which bigcommerce has provided. please help

Comment: Have you tried reporting this issue on the github project that you are using the code from?

Comment: Thanks.. i have now done that.. Is there some kind of throttlelimit for bigcommerce product updation. ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this API. It will probably help if you include the code that is causing your problem as well as tagging the appropriate language on the question (is it PHP?).

Answer (score 1):

The throttle limit is currently 20K calls per hour (rolling window, which gets reset every minute). Not being able to connect to a host might not be because of throttling. If it is throttling, you will typically get a 509 response from BC servers.

Is it possible that you are running into server issues?

Comment: yes thanks for your comments. you are right . it was server issues.. it required latest curl version.

Comment: @user2339380 If you were able to find a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer so that you can help others and earn reputation points.